# How to decode to UTF-8 String from Hex encoded string

Tags: java, javascript

I get the HTML Javascript string such as :

```
htmlString = "https\x3a\x2f\x2ftest.com"
```

But I want to decode it as below :

```
str = "https://test.com"
```

That means , I want a Util API like :

```
 public static String decodeHex(String htmlString){
   // do decode and converter here 
 }

 public static void main(String ...args){
       String htmlString = "https\x3a\x2f\x2ftest.com";
       String str = decodeHex(htmlString);
       // str should be "https://test.com"
 }
```

Does anybody know how to implement this API - decodeHex ?

Comment: http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/ is good , but I want a Java API to implement the same function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started.  I leave implementing `hexDecode` and sorting out malformed input as an exercise for you.

```
public String decode(String encoded) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++) {
    if (encoded.charAt(i) == '\' && (i + 3) < encoded.length() && encoded.charAt(i + 1) == 'x') {
      sb.append(hexDecode(encoded.substring(i + 2, i + 4)));
      i += 3;
    } else {
      sb.append(encoded.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  return sb.toString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String decode(String encoded) throws DecoderException {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < encoded.length(); i++) {
        if (encoded.charAt(i) == '\\' && (i + 3) < encoded.length() && encoded.charAt(i + 1) == 'x') {
          sb.append(new String(Hex.decodeHex(encoded.substring(i + 2, i + 4).toCharArray()),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
          i += 3;
        } else {
          sb.append(encoded.charAt(i));
        }
      }
      return sb.toString();
    }
```